# Дергается шрифт при смене opacity через transition

Tags: html, css, шрифты, transition, opacity

проблема при ховере, получается эффект изменения `font-weight` на время `transition`, как его убрать?
шрифт использую `Open-Sans` подключаю через google-fonts

```css
.header-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #528954;
}

.header-menu__item a {
  display: flex;
  padding: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-menu__item a::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #ffdd0e;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.header-menu__item a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-menu">
  <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="/">О нас</a></li>
  <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="/">Наши услуги</a></li>
  <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="/">Наши работы</a></li>
  <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="/">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
  <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="/">Статьи</a></li>
  <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="/">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Подключите сюда шрифт, иначе баг не воспроизводится - здесь всё работает корректно

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы забыли подключить сам шрифт к .header-menu__item a. Рекомендую вместе с подключением шрифта копировать и его подключение к классам. По типу: font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

Опять таки, более подробно можно почитать про font-family тут - http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-family, или же на других, более удобных вам сайтах.